# My DataContext changed. How to properly perform Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext, icommand

I am working on UserControl where I have TreeView based on custom class, build like that:

-ConnectionModel

---SchemaModel

-----SchemaCollection

-------TableModel

TreeView is working like a charm.

I added ContextMenu after click on TableModel item in TreeView.
Then I want to create binding to Command "SelectFromTab" which I declare in SideBar() class ( which is ModelView to this View ) .

How should I properly make Binding to SelectFromTab command in SideBar class?
Now DataContext of ContextMenu is set to "TableModel".

**My View** ( full .xaml )

```
<Page
  ....
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgDB4.ViewModel"
  xmlns:models="clr-namespace:ProgDB4.Model"

  xmlns:ProgDB4="clr-namespace:ProgDB4" x:Name="page" x:Class="ProgDB4.ViewModel.SideBar"

  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="SideBar">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SideBarTabControl" SelectionChanged="SideBarTabControl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem Header="Map" Content="Mapa"/>
        <TabItem Header="History" Content="History"/>
        <TabItem Header="Aliases" x:Name="tab_aliases"   Width="52">
            <Grid>
                <TreeView x:Name="AliasTree" ItemsSource="{Binding TVData}">
                    <TreeView.Resources >
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ConnectionModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding schemas}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding alias}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SchemaModel}"      ItemsSource="{Binding schema_collections}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SCHEMA_NAME}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:SchemaCollection}"  ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SCHEMA_COLLECTION_NAME}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:TableModel}" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TABLE_NAME}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >

                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="SELECT TOP 100"  Command ="{Binding SelectFromTab}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="SELECT TOP 1000"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Display indexes"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Display columns"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>

                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                </TreeView>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Text="Search..." Height="20" Grid.Row="1" TextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged" GotFocus="SearchBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="SearchBox_LostFocus"/>
</Grid>
```

**My SideBar class** :

```
public partial class SideBar : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<ConnectionModel> _TVData;
    public MainViewModel mainViewModelContext;
    public TreeView tmpAliasTree = new TreeView();

    public ICommand _SelectFromTab;
    public ICommand SelectFromTab
    {
        get
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ddd");
            return _SelectFromTab;

        }
        set { if (value != _SelectFromTab) { _SelectFromTab = value; } }
    }

    public SideBar( MainViewModel mainViewContext )
    {
        TreeViewBase = new List<ConnectionModel>(ConnectionUtilities.LoadObservableConnections());
        mainViewModelContext = mainViewContext ;

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this  ;

        // this.SelectFromTab = mainViewModelContext.SelectFromTab  ;

        var loadSideBar = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await LoadSideBar(); });
        loadSideBar.Wait();

        OnPropertyChanged("TVData");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenu` doesn't get same `DataContext` as your `UserControl`. You can set it manually.

```
private void ContextMenu_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
```

and your command will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand the problem is to bind a ContextMenu command of the TableModel item to it's parent(UserControl) DataContext "SelectFromTab" command. If so then, you need to perform the RelativeSource binding when a binding mode is FindAncestor. But here is some little problem, the ContextMenu doesn't exist in the TabModel item's visual tree. Please see the next example as the starting point to your research.

**XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="SetHereTheTypeOfDataContextMenyTargetControl">
        <Setter Property="dataGridCreateColumnAndBindIteFromCodeBehind:Attached.ParentDataContextToTag" Value="True"></Setter>
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
             <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="MenuItem One"
                              Command="{Binding CmdMenuItemOne}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="MenuItem Two" 
                              Command="{Binding CmdMenuItemTwo}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
```

**Attached Property code**

```
public class Attached
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetDataGridDataContextToTagProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SetDataGridDataContextToTag", typeof (bool), typeof (Attached), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), SetParentDataContextToTagPropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetSetDataGridDataContextToTag(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SetDataGridDataContextToTagProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetSetDataGridDataContextToTag(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(SetDataGridDataContextToTagProperty);
    }

    private static void SetParentDataContextToTagPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PerformDataContextToTagAssignment(dependencyObject as FrameworkElement, (bool)args.NewValue);
    }

    private static void PerformDataContextToTagAssignment(FrameworkElement sender, bool isAttaching)
    {
        var control = sender;
        if (control == null) return;
        if (isAttaching == false)
        {
            control.Tag = null;
        }
        else
        {
            var dataGrid = control.FindParent<PutHereTheTypeOfVisualParentWhichDataContextYouNeed>();
            if (dataGrid == null) return;
            control.Tag = dataGrid.DataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

**Helper's code**

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //get parent item
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

            //we've reached the end of the tree
            if (parentObject == null) return null;

            //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            child = parentObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need help with the code or.

Regards.